# Uncountable neighborhoods of an uncountable set

Tags: elementary-set-theory, metric-spaces

I have recently worked on the following problem and solved it. However I have encountered a "proof" of it, and I believe that proof has a logical problem but I just couldn't show it. Could you please tell me what is wrong with this proof? I made the part that bothers me bold face.

> Problem: $S \subset \mathbb{R}^2 $ is an uncountable set. Show that there exists $x \in S$ such that $N(x) \cap S$ is uncountable for all open neighborhoods $N(x)$ of $x$.

-

> Paraphrased Proof: By contradiction. Suppose there doesn't exist such point. Then $\forall x \in S$, there exists $\epsilon_x>0$ such that $N_{\epsilon_x}(x) \cap S$ is at most countable. Now since $S$ has infinitely many points take one and call it $x_1$ and for simplicity define $A_1 := N_{\epsilon_{x_1}} \cap S$. Here we know $A_1$ is countable. Continue this procedure as follows: at the $n$th step if $S \backslash \{A_1 \cup \cdots \cup A_{n-1}\} $ is nonempty, take $ x_n \in S \backslash \{A_1 \cup \cdots \cup A_{n-1}\} $. Then define $A_n = N_{\epsilon_{x_n}} \cap S$ similarly. We continue this indefinitely. **So, we should have $\cup_{n=1}^\infty A_n \supseteq S$. At the end if we don't cover a point of $S$, we include the neighborhood of that point into the union on the left.** Since $A_n$s are countable but $S$ is uncountable, we have a contradiction.

Comment: You consider neighborhoods to be open, right?

Comment: Yes, neighborhoods are open

Comment: Why do you think $\bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty}A_n\supseteq S$?

Comment: We are kind of choosing arbitrary $x_n$s, I don't know how we guarantee the union covers $S$.

Comment: @MPW I don't. That proof doesn't belong to me.

Comment: The proof is indeed flawed, but the result is valid. One way to see why, is to note that $\mathbb{R}^2$ is a second-countable space (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Second-countable_space), and thus has a countable basis at every point. Then use that fact for the point $x$ to complete the proof as in H.H. Rugh's answer.

Comment: @JustinBenfield Thanks! So we were lucky because the space was $\mathbb{R}^2$ then.

Comment: @iamvegan: Most of the nicer topological spaces of interest are actually second-countable, but you are correct in realizing that this result (and its generalization) rely crucially on second-countability.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is, as you probably feel, that you need not cover all of $S$ 'at the end'. You need to make choices that exhausts the set $S$ in a countable way. One way to do so is to note that $B_{q,n}=B((q_1,q_2),1/n)$ (rational $q_1,q_2$ and integer $n\geq 1$) is a countable  set of balls. For $s\in S$ you may find $B(s)=B_{q(s),n(s)}$ so that $s\in B(s)$ and $S\cap B(s)$ is countable. The collection of such balls is then countable (en essential point: even though $S$ a priori need not be countable the map $s\mapsto B(s)$ takes values in a countable collection so the image is countable). 
Then ${\cal B}=\{B=B_{q,n}: \exists s\in S: B(s)=B_{q,n}\}$ is a countable family, covers $S$, and  $S\subset \cup_{B\in {\cal B}}B\cap S$ is then countable.

Comment: When you say "For $x\in S$ you may find $B(s)=B_{q(s),n(s)}$" you mean "For $s\in S$" right?

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. Now I see that exhausting $S$ in a countable way was the missing part in the proof.

Comment: Indeed. Thanks for spotting the misprint.